# Create and Merge JPEG

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, jpeg, tiff

I read a TIFF image with multiple Frames using below code

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, 
                                          FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource,
                               BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,    
                               BitmapCacheOption.Default);
foreach(BitmapFrame frame in decoder.Frames)
{                
    using (Stream output = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            JpegBitmapEncoder enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(frame));
            enc.Save(output); //It overrides and finally i get the last image only
            //  outStream.CopyTo(output); this also not working.       
        }
    }

}
```

I would like to create a one JPEG image contains all the frame. But I have no idea how we can create/append a JPEG image from JpegBitmapEncoder?

Expected resulted image should be like below

```
  --------------
  |            |
  | Frame1 img |
  |            |
  |------------|
  |            |
  | Frame2 img |
  |            |
  |------------|
  |            |
  | Frame3 img |
  |            |
  |------------|
```

`outStream.CopyTo(output);` this line not at all copying bytes to file. 0 bytes always

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Calculating the dimensions of the final jpeg?  Drawing a TIFF frame to a particular location on the jpeg?  Something else?

Comment: @mbeckish, edited my question with more detail

Comment: You can't use `Frames.Add` to stack images vertically in a jpeg.  From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.frames(v=vs.110).aspx): "Only Tagged Image File Format (TIFF), Graphics Interchange Format (GIF), and Microsoft Windows Media Photo images support more than one frame. Attempts to add additional frames to formats that do not support them will result in only the first frame being encoded."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `foreach` should be inside the `using(..)` statement. Otherwise you are always creating a new output stream for (overwriting) the output file:

```
using (Stream output = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
{
   foreach(BitmapFrame frame in decoder.Frames)
   {                   
        JpegBitmapEncoder enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(frame));
        enc.Save(output); //It overrides and finally i get the last image only

        //  outStream.CopyTo(output); this also not working.       
   }
 }
```

Another aspect I noticed is in the sample code you posted you were creating a `MemoryStream` but were never using it so it was superfluous to your point.

That said, it looks like you don't just want to write the different JPEG frames to one file, one after the other but instead create a single large JPEG image that contains all the extracted TIFF frames pasted together.

In order to do so you will have to first determine the final size of your JPEG image by iterating through the TIFF frames and accumulating the height (if they are not all the same height) and the maximum width you need, if they are not all the same width.

```
int totalHeight = 0;
int maximumWidth = 0;

foreach(BitmapFrame frame in decoder.Frames)
{          
    maximumWidth = Math.Max(maximumWidth, frame.PixelWidth);         
    totalHeight = totalHeight + frame.PixelHeight;
}
```

Then, you will want to create a memory bitmap image of the right final size.

```
var visual = new DrawingVisual();
using (var ctx = visual.RenderOpen())
{
    foreach(BitmapFrame frame in decoder.Frames)
    {
        maximumWidth = Math.Max(maximumWidth, frame.PixelWidth);                     

        ctx.DrawImage(frame, new Rect(0, totalHeight, imageWidth, imageHeight));

        totalHeight = totalHeight + frame.PixelHeight;
    }
}

// Converts the Visual (DrawingVisual) into a BitmapSource
var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(maximumWidth, totalHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(visual);

// Finally, save the rendered bitmap as a jpeg to the output stream
JpegBitmapEncoder enc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));

using (Stream output = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
{
    enc.Save(output);
}
```

Comment: Yeah. But why it is not concatinating all the frames into the single JPEG image? I get only the first frame

Comment: @Billa - Read my comment to your post - you can't use `Frames.Add` to stack multiple images vertically in one jpeg.

Comment: @Billa - please see the updated answer. I haven't tested it yet but it should give you what you need..

Comment: Can you explain for `imageWidth, imageHeight` and re-arrange the code. I got confused

Comment: @Billa - what do you mean?

Comment: imageWidth value i assumed as frame.Width and managed to make it work. Is it ok or it means anything?

Comment: @Billa - yes, sorry about that! imageWidth and imageHeight were supposed to be the `frame.Width` and `frame.Height` respectively. Did it work for you?